# How to select columns with a MultiIndex in a pandas DataFrame (for seaborn scatter plot)?

Tags: python, pandas, plot, seaborn, multi-index

I have an aggregated DataFrame, with nested columns. How can I retrieve the aggregated columns, `sum` and `count`, as the x and y of a scatter plot?

[image: data screenshot]

I tried to use

```
sns.scatterplot(x="sum", y="count", data=xyz)
```

but it gave me `keyError"sum"`.

The only way it works is to retrieve `sum` and `count` as two lists, then scatterplot these two lists. But it takes a long time.

Is there any simple way to retrieve these two nested columns straight away?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From your picture it looks like you have a MultiIndex for the columns. If that's the case, you can access the columns by indexing with a tuple that specifies the values for each level:

```py
sns.scatterplot(df[('Total', 'sum')], df[('Total', 'count')])
```